# SQLite query structure. It might be a many to many relationship, I don't know

Tags: sql, sqlite

Ok, I think that I am really getting in over my head, so please bear with me!

I have a simple SQLite table that set up as such:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "game_authors";
CREATE TABLE "game_authors" ("key" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "book_key" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0, "author_key" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0);

KEY | BOOK | AUTHOR
-------------------
1     1      1
2     2      5
3     2      6
4     3      2
5     4      5
6     4      6
7     5      10
8     6      11
9     9      14
10    10     9
11    11     4
12    22     4
```

The search that I am trying to wrap my head around is finding all the book(s) by author(s).  Example: I want a list of all the book_keys that have author_key=5 and author_key=6.
   Maybe it's really easy and I can't see it in front of my face, but I can't figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

To get a book with two authors you can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT book_key
FROM game_authors
WHERE author_key = 5
  AND book_key IN (
    SELECT book_key
    FROM game_authors
    WHERE author_key = 6
    );
```

OR with an inner join with the same table, linking the two with book_key

```
SELECT a.book_key
FROM game_authors a
INNER JOIN game_authors b ON a.book_key = b.book_key
WHERE a.author_key = 5
  AND b.author_key = 6;
```

You can check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/79c5b/7) to see it working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all books that were authored by the same authors, then you could use [`INTERSECT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html). The query would look like,

```
SELECT book_key FROM game_authors WHERE author_key = 5
INTERSECT
SELECT book_key FROM game_authors WHERE author_key = 6
```

This gets a list of all books by author #5 and intersects that list with books by author #6 giving the list of books authored by both of them.

You would want an index on the `author_key` column for fast lookups. To avoid an extra table lookup to retrieve the `book_key` from the table, you could create a covering index on `(author_key, book_key)` to speed things up even more.

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/85ef0/1).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one author:

```
select * from game_authors where author_key = ?
```

and you can union a bunch of those together, if you want to know more authors:

```
select book_key from game_authors where author_key = ?
UNION
select book_key from game_authors where author_key = ?
UNION
select book_key from game_authors where author_key = ?
```

etc.